# Error de Eslint @typescript-eslint/indent

Tags: typescript, nestjs, eslint

Tengo configurado [Eslint](https://eslint.org/) en mi proyecto de **NestJS** para el cual se han configurado ciertas reglas al igual que se han utilizado las reglas que proporciona **airbnb**, pero estoy recibiendo un error muy extraño con la regla [`@typescript-eslint/indent`.](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/indent/)

ejemplo código de lo que se considera correcto:

```
  @Patch(':id')
  updateCar(
    @Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
    @Body() updateCarDto: UpdateCarDto
  ) {
    return this.carsService.update(id, updateCarDto);
  }
```

Ejemplo del la corrección que proporciona **Eslint**

```
  @Patch(':id')
  updateCar(
  @Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,
    @Body() updateCarDto: UpdateCarDto
  ) {
    return this.carsService.update(id, updateCarDto);
  }
```

por lo que el error se reconoce en esta linea: `@Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string,`

una forma en la que funciona la regla sin problemas, es si elimina `@Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe)`, quedando de la siguiente manera

```
  @Patch(':id')
  updateCar(
    id: string,
    @Body() updateCarDto: UpdateCarDto
  ) {
    return this.carsService.update(id, updateCarDto);
  }
```

la regla de **Eslint** se encuentra de la siguiente manera

```
"rules": {
    "indent": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ['error', 2],
  }
```

Comment: En el enlace de ESLint que añades pone lo siguiente: `We strongly recommend you do not use this rule or any other formatting linter rules. Use a separate dedicated formatter instead`. Entonces, ¿Porqué usar ESLint y no un [*formatter*](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting) como Prettier?

Comment: @MauricioContreras es correcto, de hecho es un problema menor, ya que tengo tambien `Prettier` instalado y en conjunto con `husky` para el `pre-commit`, por lo tanto se formatea antes de cada `commit`, pero estoy interesado en saber como solucionar esto, ya que pretendo dar formato con `eslint --fix` para algunos casos específicos y al ejecutarse después de `prettier`, dejaría un mal formato